# How to mock the Q methods in node.js unit testing with mocha and rewire?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

While writing unit tests for node.js I am facing this problem

my original file code is

```
var Q=require('q')
.
.

    .
    return Q.all(promises).then(function(data) {
            _.each(data, function(data) {
                checking.push({
                    code: data.message
                });
            });
            return {
                err: errors
            };
        });
```

My test code with rewire:

```
var testMock={
            all:function(){

                return {};
            }
        }
        testFile.__set__("Q", testMock);
```

And then it is giving 'then' of undefined...

So how to solve ???

Comment: Why are you mocking Q in the first place? What I'm seeing you do by the way is mocking Q so that `all()` returns `{}`, which of course does not have a `then` method. Is there some magic that's supposed to happen that I'm unaware of?

Comment: NO...you are correct...but I tried in multiple ways and last code sample I pasted..Don't bother about that...let me know in that case what to do?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mock Q. Q can return what you want already.
First thing `Q.all` returns an array of promises so be careful that the array of promises holds values of same structure.

In your test instead invoke your function with the promise variable set to

```
Q.resolve(data)
```

where your data is `[promise1, promise2]`

Also you will need a library to test with promises such as [Chai as promised](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised)

Maybe you wanted to promisify a loop working on data and it's more like so:

```
Q.all(data.forEach(function(oneData) {
    checking.push({
                code: oneData.message
            });
    }));
```